# Jest mock value per test

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs, babel-jest

I want to test if a library function is not called when token value is null. To do this I must change mock value of GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID between unit tests. It is stored in 'config.js' which looks like that:

```
module.exports = {
  GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID
};
```

Also it is used by withGoogleAnalytics which is a HOC. Inside it I'm importing config this way:

```
import { GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID } from 'config';
```

My test looks like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

import withGoogleAnalytics from '../withGoogleAnalytics';

jest.mock('react-ga', () => ({
  pageview: jest.fn(),
  initialize: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('config', () => ({ GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID: '123' }));

const Component = withGoogleAnalytics(() => <div />);

describe('HOC withGoogleAnalytics', () => {
  describe('render', () => {
    const shallowWrapper = shallow(<Component />);

    it('should fire initialize action', () => {
      expect(ReactGA.initialize).toHaveBeenCalledWith('123');
    });

    it('should have pageview prop set', () => {
      expect(shallowWrapper.prop('pageview')).toBe(ReactGA.pageview);
    });

    it('should not fire initialize action', () => {
      expect(ReactGA.initialize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

From what I read on StackOverflow and GitHub I should be able to do it using jest.resetModules() and jest.mockImplementation() but all the examples were mocking functions. Here I need to change string value between tests. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

A module that relies on mocked module should be imported after `jest.mock`. This won't happen if `import` is located in module scope and `jest.mock` is done per test.

Assigning `shallowWrapper` once for entire suit is bad and results in test cross-contamination.

It should be:

```
let shallowWrapper;
let withGoogleAnalytics;

beforeEach(async () => {
  shallowWrapper = shallow(<Component />)
  jest.mock('config', () => ({ GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID: '123' }));
  withGoogleAnalytics = (await import('../withGoogleAnalytics')).default;
});
```

If there's a need to test with another `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID` value, another `describe` with block with different `beforeEach` can be created.